# Find records of a certain type with the same date

Tags: ms-access

I have a database that takes in transactions from a source program. Once the transactions are in the database, they need to be cleaned up. The transactions are imported to tblTransactions and contain a TxCode and a TxDate field. If the TxCode is either "ABCD" or "WXYZ" and they are on the same date, I need to remove all but one of the transactions. I can't seem to find a way to use an SQL statement to find all transactions of a specific type that are on the same date of each other.

Comment: Good question.. How many different `TxCode`s are there?

Comment: The TxCodes would be *IRFC and *ICTS. There would only ever be one *IRFC transaction but there could be multiple *ICTS transactions. I would need to find all instances of *IRFC and *ICTS that are on the same date and remove all but one of them. Alternately, if the process is easier, I could remove all of them and then insert a single transaction after the removal.

Comment: Well, the second method is certainly easier, but how will you insert a single transaction after the removal? If you have control over that and are certain it is a good solution then deleting what you need to shouldn't be difficult

Comment: After the removal I can just insert a transaction of the *IRFC type into the table. The problem is the removal. I still don't know how to find all transactions of type *IRFC and *ICTS that are on the same date. I can select them based on a specific date, or between a range of dates, but not if their dates are the same as each other.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DELETE * FROM tblTransactions
WHERE TxCode = "ICTS" 
  AND transaction_date IN (SELECT transaction_date 
                           FROM tblTransactions
                           WHERE TxCode = "IRFC")`
```

Comment: I guess it's a little more complicated than I had originally stated. This needs to be done at a customer level (HolderID field). Each customer could have IRFC and/or ICTS transactions. If a customer only has one on a particular date, nothing needs to be done, but if they have multiple on the same date, only one of them is valid. On top of that, customers can have several variations, 1 IRFC and 3 ICTS, 0 IRFC and 6 ICTS, 1 IRFC and 0 ICTS, etc. So neither transaction needs a counterpart, although it could happen.